# D3 Tree Chart with left and right nodes on every nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, tree

I have a d3 chart that have both left and right paths/nodes. now what i'm trying to do is that on click of a node i want to append the same data ( same tree with left and right nodes ) and this new tree will be populated/centerd according to the clicked nodes x and y values, so i tried to add a new g with the x and y values i got from the object clicked.

like this

```
       var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x * 2 + "," + d.y + ")");
        drawTree2(left, "left", d);
        drawTree2(right, "right", d);
```

but its not working, please help

```js
var data = {
  "name": "Root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Branch 1"
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 2",
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 3"
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 4",
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 5"
    },


    {
      "name": "Branch 6"
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 7",
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 8"
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 9",
    }, {
      "name": "Branch 10"
    }
  ]
};


var split_index = Math.round(data.children.length / 2)

// Left data
var data1 = {
  "name": data.name,
  "children": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(0, split_index)))
};

// Right data
var data2 = {
  "name": data.name,
  "children": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.children.slice(split_index)))
};

// Create d3 hierarchies
var right = d3.hierarchy(data1);
var left = d3.hierarchy(data2);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)");

// Render both trees
drawTree(right, "right")
drawTree(left, "left")



function drawTree(root, pos) {

  var SWITCH_CONST = 1;
  if (pos === "left") {
    SWITCH_CONST = -1;
  }

  // Create new default tree layout
  var tree = d3.tree()
    // Set the size
    // Remember the tree is rotated
    // so the height is used as the width
    // and the width as the height
    .size([height, SWITCH_CONST * (width - 150) / 2]);

  tree(root)

  var nodes = root.descendants();
  var links = root.links();
  // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
  nodes[0].x = height / 2

  // Create links
  var link = g.selectAll(".link." + pos)
    .data(links)
    .join(
      enter => enter.append("path"),
      update => update,
      exit => exit.remove()
    )
    .attr("class", "link " + pos)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return "M" + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x + "C" + (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2.5 + "," + d.target.x + " " + (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2 + "," + d.source.x + " " + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x;
    });

  // Create nodes
  var node = g.selectAll(".node." + pos)
    .data(nodes)
    .join(
      enter => {
        const n = enter
          .append("g")
          .on("click", (e, d) => {
            drawSecondTree(d);
          });

        n.append("circle").attr("r", 2.5);
        n.append("text").attr("y", -10).style("text-anchor", "middle");
        return n;
      },
      update => update,
      exit => exit.remove()
    )
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node " + pos + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    })
    .select("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name
    });
}

function drawSecondTree(d) {
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x * 2 + "," + d.y + ")");
  drawTree2(left, "left", d);
  drawTree2(right, "right", d);

  function drawTree2(root, pos, d) {

    console.log(d.x, d.y);
    //return false;
    var SWITCH_CONST = 1;
    if (pos === "left") {
      SWITCH_CONST = -1;
    }

    // Create new default tree layout
    var tree = d3.tree()
      // Set the size
      // Remember the tree is rotated
      // so the height is used as the width
      // and the width as the height
      .size([height, SWITCH_CONST * (width - 150) / 2]);

    tree(root)

    var nodes = root.descendants();
    var links = root.links();
    // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
    nodes[0].x = d.y;

    // Create links
    var link = g.selectAll(".link." + pos)
      .data(links)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("path"),
        update => update,
        exit => exit.remove()
      )
      .attr("class", "link " + pos)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x + "C" + (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2.5 + "," + d.target.x + " " + (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2 + "," + d.source.x + " " + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x;
      });

    // Create nodes
    var node = g.selectAll(".node." + pos)
      .data(nodes)
      .join(
        enter => {
          const n = enter
            .append("g")
            .on("click", (e, d) => toggle(d, pos, pos === "left" ? left : right));

          n.append("circle").attr("r", 2.5);
          n.append("text").attr("y", -10).style("text-anchor", "middle");
          return n;
        },
        update => update,
        exit => exit.remove()
      )
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "node " + pos + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      })
      .select("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name
      });
  }
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #999;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.node--internal circle {
  fill: #555;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: 0.4;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="900" height="600"></svg>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you give a clear step plan of the behaviour that you want? Do you mean that the second tree is appended to the first tree? Or drawn in place of it?

Comment: Yes the second tree should start from the clicked node, basically the second tree is the child of the clicked node, but my requirement is that the child will have left and right nodes like parent, thats why i'm trying to append a new g. is there any better way of doing this ? @RubenHelsloot

Comment: If the node is on the left side of the root, won't the child nodes on the right overlap with the links from the root?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Nivaldo/CbGh2/) is closer to what you want

Comment: overlapping is fine @RubenHelsloot

Comment: This is not the functionality im looking for, here on click of a node the childrens are coming, what i want is i need half of the node in other direction, like the root. So i thought its better if create a new g and append it to the position of clicked node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I understand what you're trying to get at.

It's hard to explain because the way this is setup is a bit confusing. Basically, the main issue is the way you are creating the new `g` element's "center point" (the `translate(x,y)` part). The reason it's confusing is because you are switching X and Y coordinates in certain places. Maybe you can't get around that with how you want the map to look, which is fine, it's just hard to follow along.

I made the following changes in the `drawSecondTree` function (note the "added" and "updated" items):

```js
function drawSecondTree(d) {
  var gX = (width / 2) + d.y; // ********** added
  var gY = d.x - gX; // ********** added
  
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + gX + "," + gY + ")"); // ********** updated

  drawTree2(left, "left", d);
  drawTree2(right, "right", d);

  function drawTree2(root, pos, d) {

    console.log(d.x, d.y);
    //return false;
    var SWITCH_CONST = 1;
    if (pos === "left") {
      SWITCH_CONST = -1;
    }

    // Create new default tree layout
    var tree = d3.tree()
      // Set the size
      // Remember the tree is rotated
      // so the height is used as the width
      // and the width as the height
      .size([height, SWITCH_CONST * (width - 150) / 2]);

    tree(root)

    var nodes = root.descendants();
    var links = root.links();
    // Set both root nodes to be dead center vertically
    // nodes[0].x = d.y;
    nodes[0].x = (width / 2) + d.y; // ********** updated

    // Create links
    var link = g.selectAll(".link." + pos)
      .data(links)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("path"),
        update => update,
        exit => exit.remove()
      )
      .attr("class", "link " + pos)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x + "C" + (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2.5 + "," + d.target.x + " " + (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2 + "," + d.source.x + " " + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x;
      });

    // Create nodes
    var node = g.selectAll(".node." + pos)
      .data(nodes)
      .join(
        enter => {
          const n = enter
            .append("g")
            .on("click", (e, d) => toggle(d, pos, pos === "left" ? left : right));

          n.append("circle").attr("r", 2.5);
          n.append("text").attr("y", -10).style("text-anchor", "middle");
          return n;
        },
        update => update,
        exit => exit.remove()
      )
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "node " + pos + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
      })
      .select("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name
      });
  }
}
```

And here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joseph4tw/pen/RwRKxmW) of the full code working (with overlap of the nodes).

I would also recommend looking into using the `viewBox` of the `svg` element and figuring out how to zoom out when you add more nodes by clicking on them.

Comment: Yes, this is what i was trying to do. on click of the right nodes, the new tree nodes are not aligned properly even though both the tree have same width and height. is it trying to avoid overlap ? and is there is a better of way of doing this ? i searched a lot but was not able to find any solution @Joseph

Comment: "Is there a better way of doing this?" - I was thinking about that question last night. I think the best way to approach this is the following: when you click on a node, you modify the main data node and let the `update` function handle recalculating the tree. Please see [this doc](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) for some insight.